# Quality Of Service parameter in Ros2 Examples uses undocumented value

Tags: ros2

Until now, I just used examples of the ros documentation e.g. for the publisher

```
self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(String, 'topic', 10)
```

and it all worked well. It looks like 10 could mean, in that case, the number of kept history items - but I'm not sure !?

In the [rclpy documentation](https://docs.ros2.org/galactic/api/rclpy/api/qos.html), there is no hint about what 10 could mean in that case.

I even looked at the [source code](https://github.com/ros2/rmw/blob/rolling/rmw/include/rmw/qos_profiles.h) but I don't get it.

Can anyone clarify where to really look, to understand what the proper values are for the third parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### For C++

I might be wrong, but (for C++ *not* Python) from [rclcpp::Node Class Reference](https://docs.ros2.org/bouncy/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1_node.html#a9868f210ae092198caed452d4bee3701)

> ```
> std::shared_ptr< PublisherT >     create_publisher (const std::string &topic_name, size_t qos_history_depth, std::shared_ptr< Alloc > allocator=nullptr)
> ```

and

> ```
> std::shared_ptr< PublisherT >     create_publisher (const std::string &topic_name, const rmw_qos_profile_t &qos_profile=rmw_qos_profile_default, std::shared_ptr< Alloc > allocator=nullptr)
> ```

In both cases, the last parameter is

```
std::shared_ptr< Alloc > allocator=nullptr
```

Then from [create_publisher()](https://docs.ros2.org/bouncy/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1_node.html#a9868f210ae092198caed452d4bee3701), it says that the third parameter is

> `[in]`    **allocator**       Optional custom allocator.

---

Notes:

- [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr.html)

---

#### For Python

Actually, above, I *was* wrong.

From the link to the [rclpy documentation](https://docs.ros2.org/galactic/api/rclpy/api/qos.html) that you posted, click on the [API](https://docs.ros2.org/galactic/api/rclpy/api.html) link in the left hand side bar.

Then click on the [Publisher](https://docs.ros2.org/galactic/api/rclpy/api/topics.html#module-rclpy.publisher) link (under "Topics"):

> - [Topics](https://docs.ros2.org/galactic/api/rclpy/api/topics.html)
>
>   - [Publisher](https://docs.ros2.org/galactic/api/rclpy/api/topics.html#module-rclpy.publisher)
>   - [Subscription](https://docs.ros2.org/galactic/api/rclpy/api/topics.html#module-rclpy.subscription)

Read the warning (ignore the typo):

> Warning:
>
> Users should not create a publisher with this constuctor, instead they should call [`Node.create_publisher()`](https://docs.ros2.org/galactic/api/rclpy/api/node.html#rclpy.node.Node.create_publisher).

Click the link to [`Node.create_publisher()`](https://docs.ros2.org/galactic/api/rclpy/api/node.html#rclpy.node.Node.create_publisher)

Looking at

```
create_publisher(msg_type, topic, qos_profile, *, callback_group=None, event_callbacks=None, qos_overriding_options=None)
```

The third parameter is

> - **qos_profile** (`Union[QoSProfile, int]`) – A QoSProfile or a history depth to apply to the publisher. In the case that a history depth is provided, the QoS history is set to KEEP_LAST, the QoS history depth is set to the value of the parameter, and all other QoS settings are set to their default values.